# Google App Engine with GWT Fails

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt

I am attempting to run the sample GWT application with Google App Engine. I simply installed the Google Plugin for Eclipse and created a new project that uses both GWT and GAE, with the sample code project. The library versions that I'm using are: JDK-1.7.0_55; GAE-1.6.4; GWT-2.6.0. I'm getting the following exception when I try to run locally:

```
Initializing App Engine server
Jun 14, 2014 11:36:48 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger info
INFO: Logging to JettyLogger(null) via com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger
Jun 14, 2014 11:36:48 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader readAppEngineWebXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Andy\workspace\GAETest\war\WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml
Jun 14, 2014 11:36:48 PM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
INFO: Successfully processed C:\Users\Andy\workspace\GAETest\war\WEB-INF/web.xml
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.setSystemProperties(AbstractContainerService.java:438)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.staticInitialize(AbstractContainerService.java:386)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.loadAppEngineWebXml(AbstractContainerService.java:369)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:237)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:146)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher.start(AppEngineLauncher.java:97)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:522)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1104)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:844)
  at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:322)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.appengine.api.utils.SystemProperty
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerClassLoader.loadClass(DevAppServerClassLoader.java:87)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
  ... 10 more
```

I've tried adding various jar files that include the SystemProperty class, but I nothing seems to work correctly. I would really appreciate any suggestions or direction on this ... I know that it should work in some form, since I've seen GWT applications running on GAE.

Comment: If you are working on a new project, use the latest App Engine SDK (currently 1.9.6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that appengine-api.jar (choose one that comes with the App Engine SDK) is included in `/war/WEB-INF/lib/` folder. It's not enough to add it to your classpath. Eclipse should give you a warning in Problems tab.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help Andrei! I updated to the latest GAE SDK and everything now appears to work. The appengine-api jar files in the /war/WEB-INF/lib directory are named appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.6.jar and appengine-api-labs.jar.  The GPE added these automatically. Now I can move on to actually try to deploy an app to the appspot.